# Is $hook a global variable in WordPress

Tags: php, functions, hooks

```
// only run on dashboard page
if ( 'index.php' != $hook ) {
    return;
}
```

There is a plugin on the Wordpress.org repository that checks PHP current version. I happened to read its code and came across the above code.

the comment tells everything that only runs on the Dashboard page.

But is $hook a global WP function? I am unable to make a sense of this. Please help me or in case if any suggested readings.

Display-php-version.php →

```
function dpv_enqueue_script( $hook ) {

    // only run on dashboard page
    if ( 'index.php' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }

    // enqueue script to show PHP version
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dpv_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dpv.js' );

    // pass the PHP version to JavaScript
    wp_localize_script( 'dpv_script', 'dpvObj', array(
        'phpVersion' => phpversion()
    ) );

}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'dpv_enqueue_script' );
```

Code on dpv.js →

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#wp-version-message").after("<p>Running PHP version: <b style='color:green;'>" + dpvObj.phpVersion + "</b></p>");
});
```

Comment: Can you please include the full function that you took these lines from, this will give better context and make the question easy to answer.

Comment: Ofcourse. Just a minute.

Comment: Added an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - so, firstly you should know that it is a variable and not a function - in php this is indicated by the dollar symbol before the name: `$variable` as opposed to `function()`

Second, you should note that `$hook` is passed as a parameter to the function block - like so:

```php
function_name( $hook ){

    // this makes the variable $hook available inside the function - not globally.
    echo $hook;

}
```

So, `$hook` is actually passed to the function from the "hook" [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) which you can read on the codex page describes the value as $hook as:

**Parameters**

```
$hook_suffix
(string) The current admin page.
```

So, the answer is that $hook is not a global variable, nor a function ( essentially all WordPress functions are global, but that is another point ) - it is a local variable passed into the scope of the function hooked to the action.

Comment: index.php is the default page of the wp-admin ( same for the front-end, but in this case it is themes/theme-name/index.php ) - and the value of $hook will include the string file name ( which might include querystring parameters also ) - this value will only be "index.php" on the dashboard.

Comment: the plugin runs on all admin and frontend pages, but it does not need to take actions or do anything on every page load, so this $hook is being used to check which page is currently being viewed and then decide - based on that check - if the plugin should take actions, or not -- return false;

Comment: Right - it's a way to keep the whole WordPress "Application" more efficient - as WP will run everything thrown at it - this way at least some functions are not loaded, or assets not enqueued - badly made themes or plugins can easily try to run inside the admin, when this is pointless, these hooks try to resolve that.

Comment: Also, note there are more general functions to help, such as is_admin() - this simple check can be used to unhook most frontend code that does not need to run inside the admin.

Comment: So if `is_admin` gives the boolean true then don't run that function in the admin section anywhere.

Comment: is_admin() === false .. yeh, it's a function, not a variable ;)

Comment: I have one more question: `    if ( 'index.php' != $hook ) {` $hook is a parameter, but I could not understand how it gets assigned to pages such as index.php or page.php on front end pages or anything else in admin pages? because we are comparing → `    if ( 'index.php' != $hook ) {` that means it gets assigned.

Comment: $hook is a local variable - local to the function it is passed to - the value of $hook is passed from the action, which calculates the string value to pass - in the case of the WP admin dashboard this is index.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118451/discussion-between-intense2020-and-q-studio).